# HttpPost not sending params once over a certain size

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

Here is the code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
PostMethod method = new PostMethod(SERVER_URL);
NameValuePair[] data = {
                new NameValuePair("html", html)
};
method.setRequestBody(data);
```

Once the value for the html var goes over a certain size all params become null for the receiving URL. Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you sure that the error is in the sending, not in the receiving? What size are we talking about and what is receiving the data?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a fault on the client side.  I suspect that you may be hitting a server-side limit; e.g. a request-size limit specified in the web container configuration ... or a front-end.

Comment: For testing purposes I have it pointed at a local server too, Tomcat to be more specific. I use the same server for uploading bigger documents so I don't think that is the case. But thanks.